# Is possible to write a shape file with custom attributes definition using geotools?

Tags: java, shapefile, geotools

I need to create a shape file with custom attribues. Particularly my problem is about Double that is write like `Number,33,31` and I need `Number,10,3`.

I'm using `SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder` for create the fields definitions an to method `buildFeatureType()` for build it.

Is there any chance to do it with `org.geotools`?

```
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.setName("Location");

    builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
    java.lang.Class<?> colClass = java.lang.Class.forName(geometryClass);
    builder.add("the_geom", colClass);
    for (Entry<String, java.lang.Class<?>> m : map.entrySet()) {

        if (!GeometryConverter.isGeometryType(m.getValue().getClass())) {
            builder.add(m.getKey(), m.getValue());
        }

    }
    // build the type
    final SimpleFeatureType LOCATION = builder.buildFeatureType();
    return LOCATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, [looking at the code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/shapefile/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/shapefile/ShapefileDataStore.java#L381) shows the sizes to be hardcoded into the DataStoreFactory.

I guess if you absolutely have to change the format you could override [`createDbaseHeader`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/shapefile/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/shapefile/ShapefileDataStore.java#L356) to do so but it seems like a lot of work for no real benefit.